# Strange behavior of the system when pressing Ctrl, Shift or mouse

Tags: keyboard, input

It all started with the fact that I decided to try Fedora, after installing and configuring the system, I periodically began to notice the strange behavior of some programs, mostly I work with Pycharm CE, WPS office, etc. I thought that I had misconfigured the system and decided to return to Ubuntu for a while, but then again I noticed these problems. This is the first time I've encountered something like this in a year of working with Ubuntu and Linux. I thought it might be related to GNOME Extensions, I disabled all extensions, but it didn't help. Also, similar errors occur when switching windows to Alt+Tab and Win+Tab.

Also, a huge number of spaces are automatically printed in the office program, up to 20 pages filled with spaces can be printed in a couple of seconds, this also happens after switching the window.
[image]

I have attached links to the video because it is quite difficult to describe it in both Russian and English

[issue-video-1](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ArOk54MA-IYKVZZCBgp1YlVSjOQxia2N/view?usp=sharing)

[issue-video-2](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pHZACd5KFwW38XeB5sXCYH_1K9hg30gK/view?usp=sharing)

[issue-video-3](https://drive.google.com/file/d/10eF6DTU7dHWIbKwhJFddaFXksZo2EdHl/view?usp=sharing)

[issue-video-4](https://drive.google.com/file/d/12OcGO5OhHiGwhVfmQ3uxs-w5EAbF6lYS/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: What happens when you do it on an `xev` window? What keys are you trying to press? What keys do you think are actually received by your pycharm/wps?

Comment: I didn't quite understand what xev means. But it looks like a key sticking or a combination is triggered. I also assume that Tab has something to do with this

Comment: xev is a command that you can enter in a terminal window (the termial in PyCharm also works). Once it shows up, click inside the window, then try entering the keys you are having trouble with. What keys does it report in the terminal?

Comment: the keys are displayed correctly, when press Enter, keycode 36 appears (keysym 0xff0d, Return),
when press Ctrl keycode 37 (keysym 0xffe3, Control_L),
when press Shift keycode 50 (keysym 0xffe1, Shift_L),
when press Alt keycode 64 (keysym 0xffe9, Alt_L)

Comment: Video 1. Shift+F4 is received 2. I don't know what you are trying to show except that the website loads slowly 3. You are inserting a table, but I don't know which key 4. You might be describing somehow the key W being held down with Ctrl Have you tried this if the keys seem to be stuck down: 1. Switch to the window 2. Press the corresponding keys 3. Release them 4. Switch keyboard language 5. Repeat steps 1-3 6. Repeat steps 4-5

Comment: In the picture, I had a table in the document initially, but after switching the window to WPS office, it became like this.
On the first video, when trying to open a file main.py , an extraneous file opens, new windows appear when you try to close it
In the browser video, when you try to paste Ctrl+C from the clipboard, the tab closes
And I didn't press the W key along with Ctrl, besides, sometimes I'm on the Russian layout and the same thing happens.

Comment: I've tried different ways to solve this problem, checked different keys, pressed Ctrl, released Ctrl, changed windows, but only rebooting helps solve this problem for a while.

Moreover, it is impossible to predict when such behavior of the system will begin, every time it happens by accident. I can work in pycharm for hours and not notice problems, but sometimes they can occur immediately after starting the program.

I will try to apply your advice, thanks